# Change job names in ADLA when using pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have jobs running in ADLA using U-SQL scripts that are scheduled with data factory pipelines. The job names appear in ADLA as some id for e.g"ADF-das783bb-9dsb-4123-9420-ddaklsdlm65c1". Is there a way to rename these jobs so that I can differentiate between them?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are running these from azure data factory, these jobs should be displaying the azure data factory activity name, by default.

Something like:

act_adla_usql_AccountingData-2018-04-04T18:57:28Z

where [act_adla_usql_AccountingData] is the ADF activity name.

Are you running these via ADF? and are you naming these?